# CSS - Image looks differently when adding it dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo7rf71q/4/), to which I would like to add background image dynamically. I am trying to pass it like so:

```
<div class="card" style="background:url(http://media.comicbook.com/2016/05/captain-america-civil-war-02082016-182755.png), #0a0a0a;">
```

But then the image is not the same size as when it is in set in the css file. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `background` is a shorthand property for all background related properties. So setting it on the `style` overrides all other properties.

The same will happen in CSS if you move that property after all the other ones.

So in CSS you have (*and it works*)

```
  background:url(http://media.comicbook.com/2016/05/captain-america-civil-war-02082016-182755.png), #0a0a0a;
  background-position: -60px 42px, 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70% 88%;
```

but if you change it to

```
  background-position: -60px 42px, 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70% 88%;
  background:url(http://media.comicbook.com/2016/05/captain-america-civil-war-02082016-182755.png), #0a0a0a;
```

It will not.

---

The solutin is to just set the `style="background-image:url('...');background-color:#0a0a0a"` and not the whole `background`.

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/zo7rf71q/5/

Answer (score 2):

If you use `background` in your HTMLs style attribute, this will overwrite all the other CSS defined in your style guide.

You need to place `!important` all over the background properties in your CSS, like:

```
.card {
  background-position: -60px 42px, 0 !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 70% 88% !important;
}
```

Updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo7rf71q/6/)**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine with you but it's not recommended to write inline CSS

```
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(http://media.comicbook.com/2016/05/captain-america-civil-war-02082016-182755.png) no-repeat;">
</div>
```